# Deciding schema for site with articles with editable tags?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, database-schema, flask-sqlalchemy

I am making a blog like application and I need to have articles which have tags that are editable and deletion of tags will reflect change in the articles too. I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy and PostgresSQL.

I tried searching a lot but I couldn't find anything and I didn't quite follow what's given in the documentation. (http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/models.html#many-to-many-relationships)

```
tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
    db.Column('page_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('page.id'))
)

class Page(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags,
        backref=db.backref('pages', lazy='dynamic'))

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

But this leads me to think I'll have to use a many-to-many relation. Can someone please explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original code is correct, something similar does work. If this will be models.py

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

tags = db.Table('tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'))
)

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), index=True, unique=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(500), index=True)
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=tags,
        backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r %r>' % (self.title, self.tags)

class Tag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tag %r>' % (self.name)
```

You will be able to access the tags as models.Post.tags
and this will be of type `List` containing all elements of type `models.Tag` so that can be easily used.